# Jagged google font and bolded foreign characters in windows

Tags: css, windows, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I am using the google font [Titillium web](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Titillium+Web) for my website.  It's gorgeous on  my mac but when I view it on windows - chrome and IE - and click the polish flag to show the polish text, the polish characters are in bold (I think they are using a different font).  These characters exist inside the font so I don't know why it's not using them.  Also, the edges of the font is all jagged.

Here is my [website](http://pen.huddersfieldwebsitedesigner.co.uk/).

Comment: Have You selected `Latin Extended (latin-ext)` on google.com/webfont to get extended latin characters.

Comment: FWIW it also looks jagged on Google's site in Chrome on the PC (note the difference between the "character set" tab and the "pairings" tab): http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Titillium+Web#pairings

Comment: I have check it. You haven't selected `Latin Extended (latin-ext)` and You are using only latin characters. try this link to font, it's working: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: Thank you.  The letters display properly now in all but windows Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using `font-weight: 500;`on some of the text which is not included in the google font. This might account for the jagged appearance.